# How secure is VirtualBox's VM encryption?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, security, encryption

I'm using VirtualBox 7 on Windows 11.

1. How secure is their [disk image encryption](https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/admin/diskencryption.html)?
2. Where is the encryption key stored?
3. If a third party gets access to the computer when the VM is  turned off, what are the attack vectors?

Comment: so it uses AES 128/256 in XTS mode which is reasonable strong, but be sure to understand the "limitations" section of your linked document. anyone who can get access to process memory while the VM is running can extract the keys. consider that when thinking about your threat model, and usecases for the encryption

Comment: @FrankThomas I'm a journalist so this is crucial for me for when I travel. If the VM is encrypted, is the config file still stored outside? If so, is the config encrypted too?

Comment: per your document, the DEK (the keys) in the VM configuration are stored in an encrypted form while the VM is off. use a long-and-strong passphrase to protect them. That said if the VM is running, someone with deep (likely physical) access to the system can grab the DEK(s) in an unencrypted form from memory.  If your threat model literally includes the KGB kicking down your hotel room door, I would probably not count on it and seek professional advise (and expect to pay for the tools you are using). VBox is great and all, but if lives are on the line...

Comment: Would I be better off using an external SSD with veracrypt?

Comment: I don't know if anyone here would be willing to offer an opinion on what would constitute "better off". Veracrypt is also very nice, but I believe it does suffer the same issue if the device/volume are mounted (Truecrypt also had the same problem for devices), I do see value in the VM, as it limits leakage of your encrypted data within your host OS (like thumbnails, tmp files, mrus, etc), so the best I can offer is an encrypted VM with a local veracrypt file-volume that you mount exactly when you need it and unmount when you are done with it. but don't bet your life on my advice.

Comment: If I use an external SSD with veracrypt, could it leak tmp files, thumbnails and other files to the host? What else could it leak?

Comment: I can't provide an exhaustive list. its not files, but information about files, like the thumbnail of an image, or a filename/path in a Most Recently Used list. finally, don't underestimate the 5$ wrench: https://m.xkcd.com/538/

Comment: well I guess in the case of MS office ~ files, it can be the actual file. either way I think you are on the right track with a VM. the idea is layers of defense. its remarkably hard to not make any mistakes, so knowing your adversary and defining your threat model is critical.

Comment: @FrankThomas What if the VM is actually stored in the Veracrypt encrypted external SSD?

Comment: @FrankThomas Based on your comment I got the feeling you think paranoidrunner is searching for a gratis solution. But the VBox encryption requires the Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack which is not free free commercial purposes (I would consider a journalist to be a commercial user). Therefore if I am not mistaken paranoidrunner would already have to pay for this solution....

Comment: Some of the guys here know there stuff - nevertheless you may well get higher quality answers from security.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Veradisk provides plausible deniability if set up correctly and if that is important.  (Not what you asked, but maybe relevant)

Comment: What's the attack scenario for you as journalist? Possibly, using Bitlocker inside the VM would be better (in case your guest OS is win8 or higher).

Comment: @Robert, sorry for the misunderstanding, no this is not about closed source vs open source. This is more like when you go to court you need a lawyer. When you go to the hospital, you need a doctor/nurse. Advice from a forum thread is not sufficient. Likewise free tools may not be the best fit for the usecase.

Comment: Better off…Is BitLocker protected host, with BitLocker protected guests….don’t believe the hog wash in the news that BitLocker can be bypassed, the hardware where that’s possible is very old and had a very old dTPM and less secure BitLocker protectors enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So other discussion aside, to respond to your questions;

1. The encryption itself is AES256 in XTS mode, which makes it "Medium-High" strength encryption. The devil is in the details however. Most crypto-fails occur due to improper implementation of the cipher algorithm, not the algorithm itself. Its hard to write secure code adjacent to encryption operations. We have no means to assess oracle's implementation.
2. The keys are stored in an encrypted form in the VM config files, in the [Machine Folder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/admin/vboxconfigdata.html). These keys are password protected, and you are encouraged to use a long-Strong passphrase.
3. Attack vectors for physical access include:

   - modifying system hardware or firmware or installing malware to the host (perhaps using an [Evil-Butler/maid attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evil_maid_attack)) that will capture passphrases or keys once you subsequently start up the VM.
   - There are also "[ColdBoot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_boot_attack)" attacks, aimed at recovering keys from memory shortly after the VM is shutdown or forced to crash.
   - AES256 is not entirely unbreakable if your adversary is a motivated nation-state level entity, especially if oracle made any mistake in implementing the encryption algorithm within their product.
   - Or there's always the $5 wrench.